# minimal azure node.js config serves .js files as plain text instead of processing them

Tags: node.js, iis, azure, iisnode

I want to configure azure "website" service to use `web.config` of my own (better log control). I created a simple `web.config` in the root of my `git` deploying `node.js` project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="src\server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After i deploy and access azure website it shows me content of `src\server.js` instead of processing it as `iisnode` app :(. I know that it's some stupid error, but googling this out is surprisingly painful - all my search spells for "plain text" are repelled by countless "how to server static content via iisnode" articles :(. And learning all iis/iisnode/web.config machinery from scratch is kinda overkill for my simple task. Any hints what to add into this `web.config` so `iis` will process `server.js` as `iisnode` script and not as a plain text?

**Update**

Examining node.js repository created via azure wizard, I figured out that problem occurs only if `server.js` is located is `src` subdirectory. If it's located in root directory all works fine. Any hints why such behaviour for `iisnode`? I want subdirs :(. Any documentation that they are not allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you need to add a `rewrite` rule to your `web.config`. The IISNode module relies on the IIS URL Rewrite module to route requests to your NodeJS application.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="iisnode">
      <match url="src/*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Sources**

- [Hosting express node.js applications in IIS using iisnode](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-express-nodejs-applications-in.html)
- [Enabling a Node.js Server-Side App on Windows Azure](http://devproconnections.com/windows-azure-development/enabling-nodejs-server-side-app-windows-azure)